# How to inject cookies in the Authorization header when they are store in httpOnly

Tags: vue.js, cookies, jwt, nestjs, token

I store my token in cookies this way (server side) :

```
res.cookie('access_token', token. access_token, { httpOnly: true });
```

Therefore on the client side I could not inject it into the Authorization header since they're stored in httpOnly, anyone has an issue ? Or i'm required to extract the token manually on the server side to put it in the header ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access HttpOnly tokens from JavaScript, that is the purpose of that attribute.

A better approach is to not handle tokens at all in the browser and instead use the BFF-pattern ([Backends for Frontends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/backends-for-frontends)) as described in this video:

[alert‘OAuth 2 0’; // The impact of XSS on OAuth 2 0 in SPAs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw&t=2618s)